# Can/Should I undo an edit when an answer refers to parts of the question that I changed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

Recently I edited a question but then it turned out that while I was editing someone else gave an answer where he is cited parts of the question that I changed.

Should I undo my edits when this happens?

Can I cancel an edit while it's pending to be reviewed?

Wouldn't it be nice to have some mechanism for citations such that parts of the question that are cited cannot be edited (or at least to get a notification while editing)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just edit the answer to adjust the quotation to be what you edited the text to, if doing that makes sense in context.  If not, simply link to the revision that the quote was taken from.

That is, unless the edit to the question is changing the meaning of the question being asked, in which case, the edit *shouldn't be made at all* regardless of whether or not there is an answer referencing an earlier revision.  You should be editing the question to add additional information, or to clarify what is being asked; you shouldn't be editing the question to *ask something completely new/different*.

Comment: To make a minor addition to this fine answer, if the answer is quoting the question and asking something of the OP, that's a horrible answer which should have been a comment anyway, so don't worry about invalidating those :).

Comment: I also like to remove irrelevant parts. Mostly after the answers though.